# Google login to app (domain users only) - correct setup

Tags: python-2.7, google-app-engine, google-identity

Beginning to secure my App with Google Login (for users on my domain).

I'm using this as an overall reference:
https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/users/

I have added the code to my MainPage handler:

```
class MainPage(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
    user = users.get_current_user()
        if user:
            logout_url = users.create_logout_url('/')
        else:
            login_url = users.create_login_url('/')
    template = JINJA_ENVIRONMENT.get_template('/templates/base.html')  
    self.response.out.write(template.render())
```

I updated the app.yaml for this handler:

```
 - url: /
   script: main.app
   login: required
```

I've tested on Appengine local and the dev version of the sign in page comes up as expected.

**First question** - Do I need to add the code to all of my page handlers as I did for MainPage? and similarly do I need to add login:required to each of main handlers in app.yaml?

In GCP Cloud Console I have gone to Project>AppEngine>Settings>Edit as the doc suggests. After editing I now have:

```
Google login cookie expiry  Default (1 day)
Referrers   Google Apps domain: *********.com.au
Email API authorised senders    None
```

**Second Question** Is this all that's required to ensure only users from my Google Apps domain can login to this app?

I seem at the moment when testing locally to still be able to login even now this has been restricted to users from the domain ... does this restriction only apply once the app is deploy live to the cloud?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to handle OAuth 2.0(Google authentication) is to use the App Engine [Python decorators](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Python_syntax_and_semantics#Decorators) supplied by Google API client library. These decorators handle all of the OAuth 2.0 steps without you having to use any Flow, Credentials, or Storage objects.

- OAuth2Decorator: Use the [OAuth2Decorator](https://oauth2client.readthedocs.io/en/latest/source/oauth2client.contrib.appengine.html#oauth2client.contrib.appengine.OAuth2Decorator) class to contruct a
  decorator with your client ID and secret.
- OAuth2DecoratorFromClientSecrets: Use the
  [OAuth2DecoratorFromClientSecrets](https://oauth2client.readthedocs.io/en/latest/source/oauth2client.contrib.appengine.html#oauth2client.contrib.appengine.OAuth2DecoratorFromClientSecrets) class to contruct a decorator using 
  a client_secrets.json file described in the flow_from_clientsecrets()
  section of the OAuth 2.0 page.

Please refer [this](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/guide/google_app_engine) document for further details.

```
from apiclient.discovery import build
from google.appengine.ext import webapp
from oauth2client.contrib.appengine import OAuth2Decorator

decorator = OAuth2Decorator(
  client_id='your_client_id',
  client_secret='your_client_secret',
  scope='https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar')

service = build('calendar', 'v3')

class MainHandler(webapp.RequestHandler):

  @decorator.oauth_required
  def get(self):
    # Get the authorized Http object created by the decorator.
    http = decorator.http()
    # Call the service using the authorized Http object.
    request = service.events().list(calendarId='primary')
    response = request.execute(http=http)
    ...
```